# Editing comments

Tags: bug, editing

On other stack exchanges, I can edit my comments (albeit for a limited period of time). Why can't we do it here? I find it even more important here than in other SEs because I use a lot of LaTeX and too often it's not obvious at first whether or not the LaTeX will "compile" properly (no missing brackets, dollar signs, etc.). I find the LaTeX error after posting the comment, and find myself having to delete the comment and start over again.

I see why we don't want users to be able to edit a comment 5 months later after 100 people have replied to the comment, and then the original commenter changes their mind. But is it not possible to allow edits for 15 seconds?

I have given a screenshot of what my comments look like:

[image]

I'm using the most recent version of Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Comments are editable for 5 minutes after creation. I don't know what makes you think you can't edit them; I just edited this very comment to add this sentence.

Comment: In the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange, I just made a comment to see if the pencil icon next to it would appear, but the only button that appears is the X, for deleting the comment.

Comment: Furthermore, I can't seem to edit even the comment I just made here! Maybe it's something wrong with my browser? I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Ubuntu. How do I edit the comment?

Comment: For me the only button I get is the delete button. I am actively trying right now!

Comment: As this is a request for something that *should already* be implemented, but doesn't seem to be working for whatever reason, I've edited the tag from [meta-tag:feature-request] to [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: Looks like edits are working for me, with the typical 5-minute limit.  The "_edit_" link will tend to disappear after the 5-minute limit, though deletion can happen any time.  Is the edit link absent for you, or merely not working?  And does reloading the page change anything?

Comment: I will check now. Let me see!

Comment: When I hover next to the "just now" test, if I hover to the right place, I get the "x" button for deleting the comment. Nothing I do gets me the edit button (I don't even know what it looks like). I clicked refresh and "just now" became "11 seconds ago", but there's still nothing to click that lets me edit.

Comment: I have now posted a screenshot in my question.

Comment: Silly me, I almost forgot - what OS and internet browser are you using, if you don't mind answering that?

Comment: See a few comments above.

Comment: Can not reproduce with firefox 60 on Windows

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277647/cant-edit-comments) Meta SE post seems related. Looks like an issue specific to you. I couldn't reproduce it on the latest version of Chrome (Windows 10).

Comment: As mentioned in the comments there, you could try adding `<a class="comment-edit">edit</a>` to the HTML code but that would only be a "temporary workaround". It may be possible to write up a javascript bookmarklet to add that bit automatically to the existing HTML.

Comment: Now commented there, saying that it's still a bug in the latest version of Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04